# Acer Palmatum Garnet Dissectum

Tags: shrubs

In the autumn I purchased an Acer palmatumn dissectum Garnet to grow in a tub.. I re potted it upon delivery and it did very well through the winter. I protected it during the winter and all was well. A couple of weeks ago I'd noticed buds and lots of lovely red leaves so decided to remove the winter protection. I was so very pleased with lovely plant..... BUT one Saturday this month we had very strong winds and when i realised..... it was too late.
Over the next couple of days, all the leaves had wilted and turned black and now ALL the leaves have fallen off.
My question is, will this plant survive and come again next year?, or is this the end for this plant.
Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 1):

By your description, I'm guessing you might be in the UK, and if you are, you're not the only one who's had this problem with Acer palmatum trees this year. These trees are perfectly hardy and it would have been fine without winter protection (so long as it's not cold enough for the pot to freeze solid) - when you removed the protection, it would have been even more vulnerable to windy conditions and the sudden drop in overnight temperatures particularly.

It should put out new growth, but keep it in a sheltered spot, out of wind if possible, and not somewhere that gets full sun between about 11 and 3pm, if you can. Water  as necessary, when the top of the soil seems dry to the touch (I'm assuming there are drainage holes in the pot).

Comment: Yes, I'm in Essex. Drainage is all good. Planted using John Innes no.2. Not been over or under watered.  It was definitely the wind which caused it on that Saturday...Will it come back again even though it now has no leaves at all ???

Comment: If the new  leaves just got destroyed  by the weather, but the roots are fine, yes, it should produce new growth... if you add a photo, we might be able to tell if there are any little growth buds  still present.